# Popular LLVM version

Tags: llvm

First I'm sorry for my poor English and ambiguous questions.

I'm now trying to create an llvm front-end for new language that defined by me.
More detail, I'm making scanners, parsers, and IR code generators.

I'm now making IR Code generator using LLVM API(C++) such as IRBuilder, Context, Module.. etc

But i recently know that the LLVM API does not support backward compatibility.
Depending on the version, header file paths are different, or some functions and classes are not supported.

So, my question is below:

**Which LLVM version is the most popular?
What LLVM version should I use for my project?**

I want to make my project as portable.
In the other words, I want to make my project that minimize problems occurs when build my project in other environments.

Now I'm using LLVM 6.0.0svn version. That is result of following this page:
(https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html)
But i know how to install llvm previous version.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IR building API is more or less stable. As for "popularity", there is no such thing as most popular version. It is up to you, language writers, to choose what version of LLVM to use. Some languages try to closely follow tip-of-head, so they are compatible with fresh releases. Others make switch from time to time, on the need basis. Finally, there are tools like KLEE that try to keep compatibility across different version using `#ifdef`s, and this turned out to be not very hard.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the latest version as it can be difficult to find documentation for older versions and of course the newer versions provide more features.